# ASP.Net RegularExpression Validator - Parsing bug

Tags: asp.net, javascript, regex, validation

I wanted to write a regular expression using the ASP.Net RegExp validator that would ensure a field contains only numeric and decimal values, and at least one character.

```
^[0-9]{1,40}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Essentially: `[0-9]{1,40}` - meaning at least one to 40 numeric characters.

The ASP.Net regexp validator does not fire for an empty field - where there is not at least one character.

Work-around:  using the custom validator with the regexp check in Javascript:

```
 function validateMinTrans(sender, args) {
        var error = true;
        var txtMinTrans = document.getElementById('TxtMinTrans');
        var regexp = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,40}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$");
        if (txtMinTrans.value.match(regexp)) {
            alert("good");
        }
        else {
            alert("bad");
        }

        if (error)
            args.IsValid = false;
        else
            args.IsValid = true;
    }
```

Thus, I don't even have to check `txtMinTrans.length == 0`.

Wondering if anyone else has experienced this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regex validator does indeed not run unless the field has a value. However, you can also put a [**RequiredFieldValidator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28VS.80%29.aspx) pointing to the same TextBox control, so both will handle their own responsibilities against it - empty and pattern.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've had to do in the past... but but just outlining the difference in the way the same expression performs differently in the between the two.

Comment: @ElHaix so... what's the actual question?

Comment: Well, basically I was pointing out the difference in how the regex works between RequiredFieldValidator and a custom JS regex validation.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET validators don't generally fire for empty fields; you need to add a RequiredFieldValidator if you want to check for that. There's no problem with having two validators on the same field.

This allows you to have optional fields: just having the RegularExpressionValidator alone means "is either empty or matches this regular expression".